# Developing trading applications

Tags: .net, c++

I'm a developer with a .NET background and I'm dying to get into the trading applications realm.  What technologies would I have to learn to be able to develop trading applications?  I have seen C/C++, any others?  What do people use for the GUI?

Answer (score 2):

I see most technologies in the banks (e.g. C# front ends, Java backends, C/C++ for the analytics). SQL/relational databases of most flavours. Time-series and object databases aren't used that much.

What I don't see a lot of, and should see more of, is understanding of networking and real time price feeds (e.g. Tibco/Triarch). These are key to delivering data around the trading floor. An understanding of the network protocols (e.g. differences between TCP/UDP) and capacity is important to the architecture and the performance of the system (performance, in this scenario, being hugely significant).

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to you to choose two different technologies: one for GUI presentation and one for trading application server/logic.

If you have to choose from c++ and c# just go with c++ as a server and c# as a client part.

But if you are going to develop from scratch I'd recommend not to use c++ as a server side but some language with frameworks where transaction, security, ORM are already implemented.

Comment: C++ is a norm for trading apps.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a good idea to delay specific technical decisions as late as possible, particularly ones that involve implementation details rather than core domain behavior, such as the database and gui. A good technique is to develop the core domain first (I think Java and C# seem to be the big languages in this area), replacing the database with a simple dictionary, and the gui with unit tests, this way, especially with test driven development, you will end up with a tidy, clean, architecture, and less coupling between the "layers". Then its less drama if it turns out you need to use a big table db rather than a rdms for example, or a web interface rather than a desktop gui.

As far as gui goes, have a look at the MVP pattern. This preserves testability without having to resort to screen scraping tools, as well as improving maintainability. Of course other similar patterns are available depending on what you end up doing i.e. MVC for a web app, or MVVM for a WPF app.

Comment: How does this answer the OPs questio? Which is essentially "What technologies would I have to learn to be able to develop trading applications?"

Answer (score 1):

> So what exactly does the architecture consist of then

There is no recipe to develop trading apps. They come in all different flavors and the needs of someone market making thousands of options are very different from the needs of a daytrader or a broker. If you find a niche where you can actually get in and deliver something you've written yourself the most important thing to understand is probably not a specific language but how the customer works and what he needs.

Also, developing from scratch now is likely to result in an architecture that is very different to what you see in most standard products shipping. If you are not starting your own shop from scratch I'd say it is better to know how things were done efficiently 5-10 years ago than to try to get in with good knowledge about whatever architecture that happens to be most popular right now.

To generalize, I think most of the other commentators have got it right. Most (new) GUIs you see in boxed products are .NET-based whereas most servers are either java, C/C++ or a mix of them all. It will probably help to excel in at least one of them. In some segments I've seen Eclipse RCP being selected for the client side which I personally think is nice. For systems that has been in place for a few years or in-house developed systems (there are a LOT of them out there) you should expect anything.

> a C# Front-end talking to Java
>   services which invoke some c/C++ code
>   for analytics on the same machine or
>   am I way off?

You're at least going to see more and more of that and the C/C++ part is probably the part people would like to get rid of as java is getting better and better and the jumps from java to C/C++ are both expensive (depending on what you are doing) and hard to maintain.

I've been in the sector for some time now but I don't think I can come up with a more specific answer given the question's rather general nature.

Comment: Thanks for a great detailed response.  It gave me great technical insight.  Was C++ for the server logic being used in favor of Java or C# because of the runtime garbage collection?